# Best way to view RVIZ remotely

Tags: ros, rviz, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to remotely control a Husky to do SLAM. I want to control the Husky using RVIZ, but am running into a problem with RVIZ lagging. I looked at the networking tutorial on the wiki, set the IP, HOSTNAME, and MASTER_URI, and have an SSH agent set up between the laptops. I can get rviz to open but it lags horribly. I tested the code locally on the husky to ensure that the problem  was not on the husky's end, and it ran fine. Is there a better way to run rviz remotely?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104991/best-way-to-view-rviz-remotely/) by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2013-11-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you mean RViz as a GUI lags? Then you might need a better graphics card. If the data shown lags, you need a better wifi or choose less/other/compressed topics

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

New router made it better.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2013-11-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3826/pwong/) on 2013-11-30**:
What router did you end up using? I'm experiencing the same problems. gnome-system-monitor says I'm sending/receiving 1-2MiB/s which is about 1-2MB/s? That seems sufficient but with only my urdf (robot model) topic on rviz, i'm still experience tremendous lag.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-12-01**:
linksys ea2700

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2013-12-02**:
The one balto said. It makes it better, but still lags a bit.